# How to test Intuit reconnect api?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, reconnect

I am building a page that would send a request to Intuit Reconnect API to renew the Oauth Token and Token secret values. It is working. But my test Oauth values is not within 30 days of expiration. Thus the response has always been "Token Refresh Window Out of Bounds".
Is there a way around this so that I can get the success response with new token values? I would like to be able test this scenario multiple times, not just once.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/0020_reconnect_api

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The playground will allow you to specify the token duration.  More information is here:

https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D5G000004Dk5rxKAB/

Edit: This is the page that lets you specify the token/duration
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/

Comment: How can we get new accessTOken and accessTOkenSecret ? I did reconnect by client.reconnect(param). But I can't get new generated tokes.

Comment: The tokens are returned in the response from the Reconnect API call.