# Unable to reconnect to QuickBooks - either Token Refresh Window Out of Bounds or "...requires authorization"

Tags: python, api, oauth, quickbooks

I've seen this question [How to test Intuit reconnect api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006518/how-to-test-intuit-reconnect-api) but it seems its approach isn't working

I went to https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth, filled out the fields then went to https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA and did the same, as the duration I specified 3600 seconds. However, when I was trying to reconnect I either got 22: "This API requires Authorization." or  212 "Token Refresh Window Out of Bounds". These error can appear in the different order.

What's more odd is that I was able successfully upload the files using the same access token, consumer token, etc. a few times.

The bottom line is that the duration isn't working and I'm doing something wrong about it so I can't call "reconnect". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Getting same issue  with 212 code with php oauth example application: the problem that i getting timeout issue immediately after i doing login

Answer (score 0):

If you get this:

> 22: "This API requires Authorization."

It means that your request isn't signed correctly with OAuth.

If you get this:

> 212 "Token Refresh Window Out of Bounds".

It means your request wasn't within the 30-day prior-to-expiration boundary.

Since you didn't post any code, or really show us what you're doing at all, I don't think anyone else is going to be able to tell you much more about what's wrong...

Did you check your code to make sure you're using the correct tokens, and signing the request correctly?

What file upload are you talking about...?

Comment: Based on what you've told us so far, there's about a 99.999% chance that the duration *did* work, and that something else in your code or what you're doing is incorrect. It works for everyone else...

Comment: Can you provide any specifics steps so that anyone can reproduce this? I just tried it, works fine for me...